# How can I see if a .deb package inserts a repository?

Tags: package-management, deb

On Xubuntu 16.04, I want to install the latest Virtualbox package. I know that I could install it through APT and receive updates through the Ubuntu repositories, or I could add a PPA (if there was one) and receive it from there.

At this link I can either download the package or add it to `sources.list` and install it: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

But I would rather install the latest package by downloading it from their website. I if ran "`dpkg -i install packagename`", it would install the package, but would it add a new repository from which I would receive updates whenever I ran "`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`"? Can I somehow check if the package contains such a repository?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not fool-proof, but this will give a good indication:

```
dpkg-deb -c virtualbox-5.1_5.1.12-112440\~Debian\~stretch_amd64.deb|grep etc/apt
```

In this case nothing is found, so it looks like the package doesn't add a repository.

We're specifically looking for files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. It's not fool-proof because packages could add a repository in their `postinst`. You can examine the latter using

```
dpkg-deb --ctrl-tarfile virtualbox-5.1_5.1.12-112440\~Debian\~stretch_amd64.deb|tar xf - ./postinst
```

then reading the extracted `postinst` (which confirms that the package doesn't add a repository).

Comment: This doesn't find `google-chrome.list`, for example, because it's added by the postinst. I think that's a common case. Actually, Chrome is especially nasty because it rewrites the APT sources from a daily cron job (which the postinst invokes immediately).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out (I got it wrong in my comment on Serg's post); the second part about looking at `postinst` is all the more relevant. In Chrome's case, the download page does explain how to disable that behaviour (touch `/etc/default/google-chrome` before installation).

Answer (score 2):

```
dpkg-deb -c <package.deb> | grep /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```